# XXX, is founder of ABC, ..... or XXX, founder of ABC,.... which one is correct?

Tags: appositives

Which one of these is more correct?

> - XXX, is founder of ABC, was guest ....
> - XXX, founder of ABC, was guest ....

My English is not very good. I'm waiting for your opinion.

Comment: Only the second works. And that is probably the only "answer" you will get.

Comment: I've re-tagged this which might give you a clue as to the answer. At the moment this is merely proof-reading. Please [update the question](https://english.stackexchange.com/posts/506176/edit) indicating **why** you are asking. Which do you think is more right (or wrong) and why do you think that?

Comment: You can't write "XXX, is founder of ABC" for the exact same reason you didn't write "My English, is not very good".

Answer (score -1, accepted):

2nd one is correct though you should improve 
article usage
Xxx, the founder of abc, was a guest.
 Or you can say
Xxx who is the founder of abc was a guest

Comment: No, you should not add a definite article to that parenthetical. It is much more idiomatic without it.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I disagree. To me, it's the opposite. (I'd only expect the lack of an article in a newspaper headline.)